# Unable Scaffold To Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, dbcontext, razorgenerator

### Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft EntityFrameworkCore DbContextOptions`1[DonnaPerfum DataAccess Data ApplicationDbContext] while attempting to activate DonnaPerfum DataAccess Data ApplicationDbContext.

i have this error when i wanna scaffold to razor views.
ScreenShots

```html
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WAJM.jpg">AddController</a>  
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AovK.jpg">SettingUp</a>  
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEzHZ.jpg">ErrorView</a>
```

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
// Add services to the container.
var connectionString =   builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>          options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options=> options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
var app = builder.Build();
```

[--applicationDbContext--]

```
using Donna.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
    
    
namespace DonnaPerfum.DataAccess.Data
{
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options)
{
}
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't have this problem using your code. Please try rebuilding the solution and try again. If that doesn't work, try reopening VS.

Comment: If the problem persists, I suggest you create a new solution and try again.

Comment: I have few repository too should i send them too?!

Comment: If you create a new solution, you can not use them first, and you can also migrate them after the scaffolding is added successfully.

Comment: i changed every thing and start new project and do all thing again but same error happend again. i use vs2022. i searched every where and there where same error but no one could solve that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can try it:

1.Put the connection string in `ApplicationDbContext` as below

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
         if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
         {
             optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your connection string");
          }
    }
```

2.Tell the tools how to create your DbContext by [implementing the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IDesignTimeDbContextFactory interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory)

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your connection string");

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

Using both methods I can also successfully add scaffolding.

Comment: i manage to scaffold by your first solution but i had to remove parameterless class for that. and when i run app it face an error so i had to remove parameterless class when scaffolding done put it back again. is that ok?

Comment: parameterless class : public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) {    }

Comment: That's right. @Razor

Comment: [Official documentation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/).